# How to convert the string in the list to slices in python?

Tags: python, list, slice

I'm a beginner in python. I was just wandering is there any way to convert the string in the list to slices? Or anyway I can solve this problem? (please ignore the indention below and the error message is shown in the image)

```
gamers_list = []                                         
def add_gamer(gamer, gamers_list):
  if gamer.get('name') and gamer.get('availability'):
     gamers_list.append(gamer)
  else:
     print("Gamer is missing important information")
def calculate_availability(gamers_list, available_frequency):
  for gamer in gamers_list:
     for day in gamers_list['availability']:
        available_frequency[day] += 1
calculate_availability(gamers, count_availability)
print(count_availability)
```

[TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS8Ql.png)

Comment: Please add [proper code formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `gamers_list` as a `list` but you are trying to access it using a key. For starters you are appending `gamer` (a dict in itself or an object I suppose) to `gamers_list` and then you are trying to get the value for key `availability` from the list, which is wrong.

What you want is a `dict`. Either `gamers_list` is supposed to be a `dict` or you are using the wrong variable in the for loop

```py
for day in gamers_list['availability']:
```